# Error message "assign the Animation to a variable" is issued by VSC but not from Pycharm. What does the error means and how to solve it?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I programmed a something in Python in Pycharm that shows in matplotlib the movement of objects in space. All calculated with the math of the 3-body-problem. And it worked perfect in Pycharm.
THE PROBLEM:
I moved the code to a "WSL: Ubuntu" Virtual Enviroment in Visual Studio code. Now there is a error message when i run the code.
Heres the error:[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09XnJ.png)
The exakt error message: UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.

I hope you can help me and find the error!

Here is the exact code that worked on one platform but not on the other:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from matplotlib import animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter



class Planet:

    def __init__(self, x, y, x_vel, y_vel, mass, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_vel = x_vel
        self.y_vel = y_vel
        self.mass = mass
        self.color = color

        self.orbit = []

sun = Planet(0, 0, 0, 0, 1.989e30, "orange")
earth = Planet(149.6e9, 0, 0, 30e8, 5.972e24, "green")
saturn = Planet(227.9e9, 0, 0, 24e8, 6.42e24, "grey")


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.4*1.5, 4.8*1.5) )
fig.tight_layout(pad=4.0)
#---------------------------------------------------------------
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax.set(xlim=(-4.5e11, 4e11), ylim=(-4e11, 4e11)) #Bewegung Planeten
ax.set_title("Bewegung der Objekte")
ax.set_xlabel("m")
ax.set_ylabel("m")

ln1, = plt.plot([], [], color=sun.color, marker="o")
ln2, = plt.plot([], [], color=earth.color, marker="o")
ln3, = plt.plot([], [], color=saturn.color, marker="o")

#------------------------------------------------------------
bx = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
bx.set(xlim=(-0.5e8, 0.5e8), ylim=(-0.5e8, 0.5e8)) #Bewegung Sonne
bx.set_title("Bewegung Sonne")
bx.set_xlabel("m")
bx.set_ylabel("m")

lb1, = plt.plot([], [], color=sun.color, marker="o")


def dSdt(t, S):

    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, vx1, vy1, vx2, vy2, vx3, vy3 = S
    r12 = np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
    r13 = np.sqrt((x3-x1)**2 + (y3-y1)**2)
    r23 = np.sqrt((x2-x3)**2 + (y2-y3)**2)


    return [ vx1,
            vy1,
            vx2,
            vy2,
            vx3,
            vy3,
            earth.mass/r12**3 * (x2-x1) + saturn.mass/r13**3 * (x3-x1), #mass 1
            earth.mass/r12**3 * (y2-y1) + saturn.mass/r13**3 * (y3-y1),
            sun.mass/r12**3 * (x1-x2) + saturn.mass/r23**3 * (x3-x2), #mass 2
            sun.mass/r12**3 * (y1-y2) + saturn.mass/r23**3 * (y3-y2),
            sun.mass/r13**3 * (x1-x3) + earth.mass/r23**3 * (x2-x3), #mass 3
            sun.mass/r13**3 * (y1-y3) + earth.mass/r23**3 * (y2-y3)
           ]



t = np.linspace(0, 2000, 1000)

sol = solve_ivp(dSdt, (0, 2000), y0=[sun.x, sun.y, earth.x, earth.y, saturn.x, saturn.y,
                       sun.x_vel, sun.y_vel, earth.x_vel, earth.y_vel, saturn.x_vel, saturn.y_vel],
                method = 'DOP853', t_eval=t, rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-13)


t = sol.t
x1 = sol.y[0]
y1 = sol.y[1]
x2 = sol.y[2]
y2 = sol.y[3]
x3 = sol.y[4]
y3 = sol.y[5]



def animate(i):
    ln1.set_data(x1[i], y1[i])
    ln2.set_data(x2[i], y2[i])
    ln3.set_data(x3[i], y3[i])
    lb1.set_data(x1[i], y1[i])

    return  ln1, ln2, ln3, lb1



ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

When i start the code in Visual Studio code in a Jyupter notebook file than it works. But in a normal python file it dont.
I also shrinkt the code down so that in the end the little code worked.
The little code:

```
#%%
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s
)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
# %%
```

But i dont still now what the problem for the original code is.

Comment: I’m confused. If you open up a system terminal (not Pycharm and not VS Code) and execute the file, does it work?

Comment: @PaulH Thank you, I had not thought of that at all!
But still it does not work.
When i open the file over cmd, the error says module scipy not found. But I definitely installed it. I even uninstalled and installled the module 3 times!
The same is when i open the file over ubuntu there it gives me the same error message, alltrough i also installed scipy there!

Comment: sounds like you have multiple version of python installed and you're not using the correct one.

Comment: @PaulH thanks that was it!
Now theres a new error message XD,
but at least I i solved this step, to the working code.

Comment: @JialeDu yeah I would do that, but how can i upvote a comment? PaulH helped me with his comment not with a answer

Comment: Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you showed works fine for me. Make sure you are using the correct interpreter(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ==> `Python:Select Interpreter`) and have all required packages installed.

[image]

[image]